# Delete a variable from multiple lines VIM

Tags: vim, neovim

I want to delete all the lines that `linksData` is written to.

```
const linksData = [                                                                                     
    {                                                                                                     
      title: 'Docs',                                                                                      
      caption: 'quasar.dev',                                                                              
      icon: 'school',                                                                                     
      link: 'https://quasar.dev'                                                                          
    },                                                                                                    
    {                                                                                                     
      title: 'Github',                                                                                    
      caption: 'github.com/quasarframework',                                                              
      icon: 'code',                                                                                       
      link: 'https://github.com/quasarframework'                                                          
    }
]
```

I am using Vue framework, maybe that could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on answer from @SergioAraujo

`:g/linksData/norm d%`

seems to do what you want.

Comment: Sometimes, unbalaced pairs may exist in strings or comments.

Comment: @Light, you are right, but for my case the pairs were balanced. The solution worked! Thank you :) i just did `d%` with the cursor on the first line.

Comment: @m_mlvx can u please elaborate d%., i tried in my vim editor, it is deleting all content after cursor if there are any literal pairs present in the current line.But can u give proper meaning of % here. thanks :)

Comment: @girish -- Can you give an example of the "literal pairs present in the current line"?
(The `d%` in my answer is to delete text on lines with matching `[]` pairs.)

Comment: @m_mlvx for ex: { } ( ) [ ]...(not working for annotations) (may be literal pairs might not be exact word though) but can u explain the philosophy of d% in vim here

Comment: I still don't understand the "literal pairs" part, but the `d%` is simple.  The `%` finds matching pairs of enclosure punctuation, which I will call "ep" for short.  This is `()`, `{}`, and `[]`.  (For better or worse, "ep" does not include quote marks.)  And `d` deletes.  So, `d%` will delete text from the cursor to the opposite matching "ep".  Try this in Vim - use `d%` (and undo with `u`) at various points in this text to better understand how it works:  `Amazingly, {the [quick brown fox] jumps [over (the lazy) dog].} Wow.`

Answer (score 1):

Assume your cursor is on the first line, try:

```
f[di]
```

Then you'll have:

```
const linksData = []
```

Comment: Your answer is useful, but I try to delete all the lines. (including `const linksData = []`)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of "linksData" you can use:

```
:g/linksData/norm f[di[kgJ
```

After deletig the content of [] you will join the lines with no space in between, that's why we go one line up with `k` and use `gJ` instead of `j`.

Comment: I've tried it and got `const linksData = []`, @Kent solution is more stylish.